# C++, what is := used for?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, colon-equals

I'm seeing this in a program. I can't find anything on ":=". What is it used for?

The program says:

```
val1 := val1 * (val2 + result);
```

Comment: That's not a C++ operator. Are you sure this is a C++ program?

Comment: Looks like Pascal to me.

Comment: Is it Pascal (or Modula{2,3,4}, perhaps?

Comment: No its C++. I'm trying to track what a chunk of code is supposed to mean. That means it's just a typo. Thanks!

Comment: I have never seen this operator.

Comment: Please post more of the code and we can identify the language. `:=` is not a valid operator in C or C++,so this code would not compile.

Comment: @theSun: Is this in a comment or documentation then?  Pseudo-code used to document C++ programs isn't always written in C++.

Comment: It's only a typo, and I'm sure its C++.

Comment: It's a non-existent operator halfway in between the assignment operator and the proposed swap operator (:=:).

Comment: has this been #defined somewhere?

Comment: Here's what I get: `testAssign.cpp:9:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token`

Comment: @KeithNicholas, Not possible. It has to be an identifier.

Comment: Looks like Smalltalk, except for the semicolon, should be a fullstop.

Comment: Where's the code from. Is there more?

Comment: Is this inside a comment as pseudo code?

Comment: looks like Golang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely nothing.  The `:=` operator is an assignment operator in other languages.  C++, like C, uses just the `=` operator.

Answer (score 3):

It could be ALGOL 68 or Pascal but it probably is pseudo code where it is common to use := for assignments and = for comparisons. In C++ there is no := operator.